# How to convert a binary IPv6 address into hexadecimal

Tags: c++, binary, hex, type-conversion, ipv6

I am receiving a 128-bit binary address and I need to convert it into hexadecimal format. This is what I have to do:

- I will receive 128-bit binary number
- I need to divide it into 8 blocks of 16-bits each, so I will have 8 variables each having 16-bits.

  **0010000111011010   0000000011010011   0000000000000000   0010111100111011 0000001010101010   0000000011111111   0000000000000000   0000000000000000**
- Now, I need to further divide these 16-bits into 4-bits each i.e a nibble

  **0010 0001 1101 1010

    0000 0000 1101 0011

    0000 0000 0000 0000**
- So, now I will get four sub variables for each variable
- Each variable is 16-bits long and sub variables are 4-bits long
- Than, I need to convert each of these sub variables into hexadecimal

  **0010 0001 1101 1010**

  **2     1   D    A**
- Combine all the sub variables and form an IPv6 address in hexadecimal form:

  **21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:0000:0000**

Can anyone tell me how to do it in C++?

Comment: So [`inet_ntop`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html) doesn't work for you?

Comment: you know the algorithm, its simple; try to write a code for it. Ask question if you have difficulty implementing the code

Comment: @Barun I am not getting how to extract a nibble out of a 16-bit binary

Comment: If you want to do it yourself (instead of using functions which already does this) then read about bitwise operations like bitwise and (the `&` operator) and shift (the `<<` and `>>` operators).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Our libraries does not support use of inet_ntop function, any other sugesstion please

Comment: Any other constraints? Are you supposed to use shift-and-mask to extract substrings, or can you use std::bitset?

Comment: @Prats Use an integer array to store the numbers to get the nibbles or convert it to String and do a split of length 4

Comment: @MarkPlotnick please have a look at EDIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the four highest bits of a 16-bit value, you shift it right by 12 bits. This will cause the top bits to be zeroes so no masking needed. For the others you (optionally) shift right and mask out the four lowest bits with the bitwise and operator `&`.

To make the value gotten from the above steps to a hexadecimal digit in character form, then for values lower than 10 add `'0'` (if you're on a computer with with ASCII encoding), and for values at 10 or higher then subtract ten and add e.g. `'A'`.

---

There are simpler ways of course, like using e.g. `sprintf` to convert the number directly. Just get the 16-bit value into an unsigned short, and do e.g.

```
printf("%04hx\n", value_as_unsigned_short);
```

---

Let say you have the binary number `0001001010101011`. This is, in hexadecimal presentation `12ab`.

If the binary number is in an integer variable, lets say one named `value`, we can get the hexadecimal representation as a string like this:

```
// First get each digit, one by one
digit0 = value & 0x0f;  // Mask out everything but the lowest four bits
digit1 = (value >>  4) 0x0f;
digit2 = (value >>  8) 0x0f;
digit3 = value >> 12;

// Now make a string out of those four digits
char str[5];  // Four digits plus the string terminator

// If a digit is less than 10, then add '0'  to get an ASCII character
// Else decrease by ten (to get a number between 0 and 5) and add 'A'
str[0] = digit3 < 10 ? digit3 + '0' : (digit3 - 10) + 'A';
str[1] = digit2 < 10 ? digit2 + '0' : (digit2 - 10) + 'A';
str[2] = digit1 < 10 ? digit1 + '0' : (digit1 - 10) + 'A';
str[3] = digit0 < 10 ? digit0 + '0' : (digit0 - 10) + 'A';
str[4] = '\0'; // Terminate string

printf("value is in hex %s\n", str);
```

The above code will print

```
value is in hex 12AB
```

However that is a lot of code, though it can be reused for all numbers. If you already have your 16-bit number in the integer variable `value`, then it's much easier to just write

```
printf("value is in hex %04hX\n", value);
```

The result of both code snippets above will be just the same.

---

Regarding your edit:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i, aBinaryIPAddress += 2)
{
    // Take the first byte, and shift it left 8 bits, making it
    // the high byte of a 16-bit number. Then or (or add) the next
    // byte at the low 8 bits in the 16-bit number.
    // The casting is needed because we're working with 16-bit numbers
    // and not bytes.
    uint16_t value = static_cast<uint16_t>(*aBinaryIPAddress << 8) |
                     static_cast<uint16_t>(*(aBinaryIPAddress + 1));

    oss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << std::hex << value;
    if (i < 7)
        oss << ':';
}

std::cout << "Address is " << oss.str() << '\n';
```

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Well since the OP wants 16 bits, it should really be `04`. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hey, I am very new to c++, I am not getting what you are saying

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Could you please explain by giving an example, it would be really helpful

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am getting the binary input in a char pointer, I am unable to convert it into int/short

Comment: @JoachimPileborg please have a look at the EDIT

Comment: @JoachimPileborg please help me in implementing this logic to the above function

Comment: @JoachimPileborg static_cast<uint16_t>(*aBinaryIPAddress << 8) | static_cast<uint16_t>(*(aBinaryIPAddress + 1)); Could you please explain what is this line doing?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The input to function is not in the form of array, it is a 128-bits long char pointer: "00100001110110100000000011010011000000000000000000101111001110110000001010101010000000001111111111111110001010001001110001011010"

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Could you please take the input as a char pointer pointing to a 128-bit address and not as an array

Comment: @Prats Do you get the data *as a string*? If not then the array is a sequence of 128 bits, and I use an `unsigned char*` to access it. Where the data is coming from is irrelevant, 128 bits of data is 128 bits of data no matter what.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This is a magic function, it converts every nibble to  the corresponding hexadecimal value

Answer (score 3):

You can use sprintf and format specifier X to print a integer value as hexadecimal. No need to divide the blocks more than 4 bytes each. So if you have this:

```
string a = "00100001110110100000000011010011";
unsigned value = 0;
for (int i  = 0;i < a.size();++i) {
  value = value * 2 + a[i] - '0';
}
printf("%04X\n", value);
```

Will solve a big portion of your problem. I have used printf above to demonstrate the output on stdout.

Comment: Please have a look at the EDIT and help me :)